# How do I fix the routing so that I can open the site by URL?

Tags: reactjs

I set up routing on the site. When you go through different pages of the site, routing does change and everything seems to be ok, but if I copy the link and paste -- I will not be redirected anywhere, although I must redirect to the page with this url.

You can check it out here.
https://loozmax.github.io/event-urfu/

What am I doing wrong? Help me fix it, please. I'm still a rookie.

```js
render() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div id="tabs-content">
        <div className="inside-container block active tab-1">
          <div id="wrapp">
            {this.state.card.map((event_id) => {
              return (
                <Link style={styles} to={"/api/events/" + event_id.pk}>
                  <ShowCardDescription
                    idx={event_id}
                    isToggleOn={this.state.isToggleOn}
                    handleClick={this.handleClick}
                    name={event_id.title}
                    time={event_id.datetime}
                    place={event_id.place}
                  >
                    <Switch>
                      <Route path="/" exact render={() => <MainContent />} />
                      <Route
                        path="/api/events/:event_id"
                        render={(props) => {
                          return (
                            <Description
                              name={event_id.title}
                              date={event_id.datetime}
                              place={event_id.place}
                              member={event_id.members_count}
                              description={event_id.description}
                            />
                          );
                        }}
                      />
                    </Switch>
                  </ShowCardDescription>
                </Link>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi @loozmax, I cannot test it out right now but I found this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1765) and [possible solution](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1765#issuecomment-327615099) that you may try. Good luck!

Comment: I added a basename at browserRouter. Routing is still changing. But if I type manually, I'll be on the home page :(

Comment: [This](https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages) may also be helpful. You should know the problem is unlikely caused by your code but GitHub Pages doesn't natively support single-page apps.

Comment: If you are open to other free hosting services, I would recommend Netlify. Here is a tutorial about [How to deploy a React application to Netlify](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-deploy-a-react-application-to-netlify-363b8a98a985/).